# PARSE4CN1 Android push don't work

Tags: push-notification, codenameone, parse4cn1

I'm having some trouble integrating my app with the parse4cn1 lib. I followed the tutorial published on this link and the app registers normally on the Parse Server as an installation but when I try to send a push to Android devices  they simply aren't being sent.

I haven't tried on iOS yet, since I figured I'd start with Android, and I'm working with a new GUI Builder app if maybe that affects something for any reason.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to add more information to this question regarding your problem solving efforts so far

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the problem, it was related to parse not the parse4cn1 lib. I'm actually new with parse and backend in general, I wasn't aware I had to run the pm2 restart command after modifying the cloud code.

It's working now, thanks!